# Issue with loading font using JaspersReport

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports

I have an issue with loading my own font.

I've exported the font using iReports and this [tutorial](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/adding-fonts-embedding-pdf).

This resulted in having the files:

```
/resources/jasperreports_extension.properties
/resources/fonts/fontsfamily1480698239543.xml
/resources/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf
/resources/fonts/Lato-BoldItalic.ttf
/resources/fonts/Lato-Italic.ttf
/resources/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf
```

Where `jasperreports_extension.properties`:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.simple.font.families=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.Lato=fonts/fontsfamily1480698239543.xml
```

And `fontsfamily1480698239543.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
   <fontFamily name="Lato">
       <normal><![CDATA[fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf]]></normal>
       <bold><![CDATA[fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf]]></bold>
       <italic><![CDATA[fonts/Lato-Italic.ttf]]></italic>
       <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/Lato-BoldItalic.ttf]]></boldItalic>
       <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Cp1250]]></pdfEncoding>
       <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
   </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

In my report.jrxml I use the following for text:

```
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="Colored" x="119" y="93" width="161" height="15" uuid="724f085b-cb64-4d11-ac64-dc23e6f04553"/>
            <textElement markup="none">
                <font fontName="Lato" size="10" pdfEncoding="Cp1250" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Whatever]]></text>
        </staticText>

        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="198" y="200" width="154" height="24" uuid="95b310d8-19bf-4485-840f-f3f5076b225e"/>
            <textElement markup="none">
                <font size="14" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" pdfFontName="Lato" pdfEncoding="Cp1250" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Address:]]></text>
        </staticText>
```

When I am trying to generate the file, I get the following error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font: 
pdfFontName: Lato
pdfEncoding: Cp1250
isPdfEmbedded : true] with root cause
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font: 
pdfFontName: Lato
pdfEncoding: Cp1250
isPdfEmbedded : true
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getFont(JRPdfExporter.java:2176) ~[jasperreports-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I've applied changes with accordance to comment by AlexK and dada67, but this still didn't changed the font that is generated in the PDF. However, I can see the font in iReports application. I now use:

```
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="198" y="200" width="154" height="24" uuid="95b310d8-19bf-4485-840f-f3f5076b225e"/>
            <textElement markup="none">
                <font size="14" fontName="Lato"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Address:]]></text>
        </staticText>
```

Which doesn't throw any error.

Here is how I generate the pdf in java:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
JasperReport jasperReportSpec = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("reporting/Example.jrxml"));
JasperPrint jasperPrintSpec = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReportSpec, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
files.put("generatedFile", JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrintSpec));
```

Comment: Did you place jar with font at cp?

Comment: @AlexK, I only moved the content of the jar to the resources/fonts/*

Comment: Did you try to use another fonts? For example from `jasperreports-fonts-x.jar`?

Comment: If you are ok with *Java* you can try to debug with attached *source code*. I think you will resolve issue in 10 minutes in this case

Comment: I will do it as soon as I will get to computer. Should I only add the jar to class path?

Comment: Yes, only the jar (it contains ttf, xml & properties files)

Comment: @AlexK, when I am adding this jar to classpath in intellij, it asks me about the category: Classes, External Annotations, Jar Directory, JavaDocs, Native Library Location, Source Archive Directory or Sources. Which one should I choose?

Comment: You can add jar in "Project Settings" ->  "Libraries" -> "New project library". If you are familiar witn Maven maybe it a the best option to create a small project to check your issue.

Comment: Is your report empty with code you posted last time? Where is your staticText placed?

Comment: The staticText is just a part of the whole jrxml file. The file is generated with all the text. It just doesn't change the font to the one I've exported.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129698/discussion-between-alex-k-and-uksz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was that I was not loading the font in my classpath. Thanks to @AlexD, I've managed to add it using maven.

Answer (score 1):

When you use font extensions you should only set the fontName attribute.

Remove the pdfFontName, pdfEncoding and isPdfEmbedded attributes from the text elements so that the PDF exporter will use the font as defined in the font extension.

Comment: This didn't helped. I've added the font to class path, only set the fontName to 'Lato' in the <font> tag, and still I don't have the font that I expected to have, even though it is visible in iReports

Comment: Do you still have the "Could not load the following font" error?

Comment: Which export format are you looking at (PDF/HTML/viewer/other)?

Comment: I ma looking at PDF only

Comment: Is the Lato font listed in the PDF viewer (under Properties/Fonts or something similar)?

Comment: No - under 'Fonts used in this document' there is only Helvetica.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have the font extension jar (as created by iReport) on your application's classpath?

Comment: @AlexK was right. The font was not added to my classpath.