# JasperReports does not maintain fonts when exports in pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

My Java application generates a pdf file filling a JasperReports's report, but when i open the pdf file the fonts it's allways "Arial", in report is set to "DejaVu Sans".

When I use the JasperReports functions to export to pdf file everything works good (after that i've imported the .ttf file of DejaVu Sans). The problem persists only when I use the Java application.

Here is the start of one of my subreports.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sub_21" pageWidth="515" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="515" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="0" uuid="34ff3034-41c3-4268-b500-7252cbe01a14">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="acp" class="acp.pdfengine.entities.PdfData"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="376" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="181" height="21" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="7b1fe94a-28dd-42d1-b6db-ee2dcc2d7020"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{acp}.getPdfWords().getRESULT_title()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

And here is the piece of java code that fills the reports and creates the pdf:

```
filledReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, dataSource);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(filledReport, data.getPdfInfo().getResourcesPath() + data.getPdfInfo().getFileName());
```

Here is my jasperreports-fonts.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Sans" visible="true">
      <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf</normal> 
      <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf</bold> 
      <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf</italic> 
      <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf</boldItalic> 
      <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding> 
      <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded> 
      <exportFonts>
      <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export> 
      <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export> 
      </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="Pictonic" visible="false">
        <normal>
            <ttf>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.ttf</ttf>
            <svg>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.svg</svg>
            <eot>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.eot</eot>
            <woff>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.woff</woff>
        </normal>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
    </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Are you using font extensions?

Comment: Yes! But maybe i'm making some errors... I followed these instructions http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/#fontextensions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with loading font using JaspersReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937940/issue-with-loading-font-using-jaspersreport)

Comment: Your jar with font looks fines. The jrxml is also valid. I've checked similar jar - my pdf is fine. You should add *jar* (with fonts) to classpath. You can debug code with attached JasperReports source code. You can set breakpoint at *`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontUtil`* class, *`getFontInfo(String, Locale)`* method. You can check `families` List after executing this line of code `List<FontFamily> families = jasperReportsContext.getExtensions(FontFamily.class);`. Your fonts should be at this list if you put jar at classpath correctly. Try to don't set Locale for report (if you set it)

Comment: You can also try to use fonts from `jasperreports-fonts-6.x.jar` to check the you place jar to classpath in right way. You can find this jar at `<Jaspersoft Studio>/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/65/0/.cp/lib` folder

Comment: Today I noticed that the error is not caused by these settings, if I run my java application directly in netbeans it works good (all the characters in the PDF are correct), the problem occurs when I transform it in an executable file (first in a .jar file including all the libraries and then in an .exe file using Launch4J) and I run it using another program. @AlexK

Answer (score 1):

@Erald See this example of Spring Boot with Reports in Jasper, in the pom there are jasperreports dependecies.
https://github.com/karelp90/control_asp

[image: see the link to the report]

[image: see the report]